# Velocity ResourceNotFoundException when mavenizing

Tags: maven-plugin, velocity

I have two projects called **Generator** and **Executor** ( both maven projects ). I make use of apache velocity template engine to generate ( in **Generator** ) and the code generated, gets executed in **Executor**. I want the code to run from **Executor** project. I have added **Generator** as dependency and was able to run successfully by specifying absolute paths for Template files that are required while executing.

I wanted to set the template path as relative to classpaths and execute the maven command. I tried everything as said in stackoverflow queries but I guess I am definitely missing something to run **maven clean install** successfully.

```
VelocityEngine Velocity = new VelocityEngine();

Velocity.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "classpath"); 
Velocity.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class",ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());

 Velocity.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.path",templatepath);
```

The above it the snippet of setting my Velocity Engine.

```
templatepath = Templates\\ -> Set relative to classpath ( src/main/resources )
```

I get the templates as

```
Template body = Velocity.getTemplate(xmlparsepath);
```

where xmlparsepath=XMLParse.vm

Expected program flow: I need to run **mvn clean exec:java test ** from Executor project which should execute Generator project ( which generates junit test cases in executor ) and run test cases in Executor project.

I get ResourceNotFoundExceptions saying that I am unable to point to template files. But the velocity logs say the otherwise. The Velocity logs in Generator project is as below.

```
2014-07-30 10:52:00,219 - Log4JLogChute initialized using file 'velocity.log'
2014-07-30 10:52:00,219 - Initializing Velocity, Calling init()...
2014-07-30 10:52:00,219 - Starting Apache Velocity v1.7 (compiled: 2010-11-19 12:14:37)
2014-07-30 10:52:00,219 - Default Properties File: org\apache\velocity\runtime\defaults\velocity.properties
2014-07-30 10:52:00,219 - Trying to use logger class org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.AvalonLogChute
2014-07-30 10:52:00,219 - Target log system for org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.AvalonLogChute is not available (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log/format/Formatter).  Falling back to next log system...
2014-07-30 10:52:00,219 - Trying to use logger class org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute
2014-07-30 10:52:00,219 - Using logger class org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute
2014-07-30 10:52:00,235 - ResourceLoader instantiated: org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
2014-07-30 10:52:00,266 - ResourceCache: initialized (class org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceCacheImpl) with class java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap cache map.
2014-07-30 10:52:00,266 - Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Stop
2014-07-30 10:52:00,266 - Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Define
2014-07-30 10:52:00,266 - Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Break
2014-07-30 10:52:00,266 - Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Evaluate
2014-07-30 10:52:00,266 - Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Literal
2014-07-30 10:52:00,266 - Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Macro
2014-07-30 10:52:00,281 - Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Parse
2014-07-30 10:52:00,281 - Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Include
2014-07-30 10:52:00,281 - Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Foreach
2014-07-30 10:52:00,344 - Created '20' parsers.
2014-07-30 10:52:00,360 - Velocimacro : "velocimacro.library" is not set.  Trying default library: VM_global_library.vm
2014-07-30 10:52:00,360 - Could not load resource 'VM_global_library.vm' from ResourceLoader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader: ClasspathResourceLoader Error: cannot find resource VM_global_library.vm
2014-07-30 10:52:00,360 - Velocimacro : Default library not found.
2014-07-30 10:52:00,360 - Velocimacro : allowInline = true : VMs can be defined inline in templates
2014-07-30 10:52:00,360 - Velocimacro : allowInlineToOverride = false : VMs defined inline may NOT replace previous VM definitions
2014-07-30 10:52:00,360 - Velocimacro : allowInlineLocal = false : VMs defined inline will be global in scope if allowed.
2014-07-30 10:52:00,360 - Velocimacro : autoload off : VM system will not automatically reload global library macros
2014-07-30 10:52:00,391 - ResourceManager : found Templates\RootTemplate.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
2014-07-30 10:52:00,391 - ResourceManager : found Templates\XMLParse.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
2014-07-30 10:52:00,391 - ResourceManager : found Templates\XMLHeader.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
2014-07-30 10:52:00,391 - ResourceManager : found Templates\XMLFooter.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
2014-07-30 10:52:00,391 - ResourceManager : found Templates\\PackagesTemplate.vm with loader
```

Velocity logs pertaining to Executor Project.

```
2014-07-30 14:43:48,502 - Log4JLogChute initialized using file 'velocity.log'
2014-07-30 14:43:48,503 - Initializing Velocity, Calling init()...
2014-07-30 14:43:48,503 - Starting Apache Velocity v1.7 (compiled: 2010-11-19 12:14:37)
2014-07-30 14:43:48,503 - Default Properties File: org\apache\velocity\runtime\defaults\velocity.properties
2014-07-30 14:43:48,503 - Trying to use logger class org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.AvalonLogChute
2014-07-30 14:43:48,503 - Target log system for org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.AvalonLogChute is not available (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log/format/Formatter).  Falling back to next log system...
2014-07-30 14:43:48,503 - Trying to use logger class org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute
2014-07-30 14:43:48,503 - Using logger class org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute
2014-07-30 14:43:48,506 - ResourceLoader instantiated: org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
2014-07-30 14:43:48,515 - ResourceCache: initialized (class org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceCacheImpl) with class java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap cache map.
2014-07-30 14:43:48,516 - Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Stop
2014-07-30 14:43:48,517 - Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Define
2014-07-30 14:43:48,518 - Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Break
2014-07-30 14:43:48,518 - Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Evaluate
2014-07-30 14:43:48,518 - Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Literal
2014-07-30 14:43:48,519 - Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Macro
2014-07-30 14:43:48,520 - Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Parse
2014-07-30 14:43:48,521 - Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Include
2014-07-30 14:43:48,522 - Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Foreach
2014-07-30 14:43:48,545 - Created '20' parsers.
2014-07-30 14:43:48,549 - Velocimacro : "velocimacro.library" is not set.  Trying default library: VM_global_library.vm
2014-07-30 14:43:48,549 - Could not load resource 'VM_global_library.vm' from ResourceLoader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader: ClasspathResourceLoader Error: cannot find resource VM_global_library.vm
2014-07-30 14:43:48,549 - Velocimacro : Default library not found.
2014-07-30 14:43:48,549 - Velocimacro : allowInline = true : VMs can be defined inline in templates
2014-07-30 14:43:48,549 - Velocimacro : allowInlineToOverride = false : VMs defined inline may NOT replace previous VM definitions
2014-07-30 14:43:48,549 - Velocimacro : allowInlineLocal = false : VMs defined inline will be global in scope if allowed.
2014-07-30 14:43:48,549 - Velocimacro : autoload off : VM system will not automatically reload global library macros
2014-07-30 14:43:48,552 - ResourceManager : unable to find resource 'RootTemplate.vm' in any resource loader.
```

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. Please find it below. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve it guys. I was not making using of VM_global_library.vm. We need to load our templates into this field, something like below

```
  prop.setProperty("velocimacro.library", "RootTemplate.vm" );
```

And the runtime engine was able to pick up templates this way.